# duality of $L^p$ spaces with non $\sigma$ finite measure

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Why is the condition that $\mu$ (measure) is $\sigma$-finite is important for the relation
$(L^1)^{*} = L^{\infty}$? This condition is added while proving that $(L^p)^{*} = L^{q}$ where $p, q$ are conjugate exponents and $1 \leq p < \infty$. Could someone provide a counter example using counting measure and show that in the case of the measure being not $\sigma$-finite $(L^1)^{*} \neq L^{\infty}$.

Comment: If you are following Rudin Real and Complex Analysis, look up Exercise 12 in Chapter 6. This answers your question.

Comment: For the counting measure (at least if you use the whole power set as the $\sigma$ algebra), you always have $(L^1)^\ast = L^\infty$, so you cannot use that as a counterexample. For a functional $\varphi$ on $\ell^1$, simply define $x_i := \varphi(\delta_i)$, where $(\delta_i)_j = 0$ if $i\neq j$ and $1$ otherwise. It is not hard to check $(x_i)_i \in \ell^\infty$ and $\varphi(y) = \langle y, x \rangle$ for all $x \in \ell^1$.

Comment: $(L_1)^*=L_\infty$ iff $\mu$ [is localizable](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/144508/when-l-infty-is-1-injective/144521#144521)